# Why is PHP saving each session in multiple directories?

Tags: php, google-chrome, server, session-cookies

I noticed PHP saves each session on my domain in multiple directories.
I noticed this when i checked the "path" under each cookie in my domain.
It saves the user's email session for instance in my "ajax", "pages", "subpages", "root" path.
This is unfortunately bloating the number of cookies on my domain since i extended each session with cookies so as to extend their lifespan. 
Is it right to limit this directory to one? And if yes, how do i go about it?

Comment: well you should tell us if you use a framework, show you code too. Also know the cookie is saved on the visitor's browser, on your side, you save only the sessions

Comment: Thanks @zeflex I am using vanilla php and i am noticing this on my localhost server as well as my live server. As for the code, i left that out because it is irrelevant in the sense that i use the usual $_SESSION["name"] = "Jane doe";